# 'for' tag was never closed / if elsif else in liquid logic to include a page?

Tags: ruby, liquid, jekyll-theme

My Jekyll version is 3.8.6.

If I have too many elseif I get a for logic error where no for loop was written. If I remove one elseif, it works.

**This does not work:**

```
{% if page.jsontype == "page" %}
    {% include pageJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "collection" %}
    {% include collectionJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "post" %}
    {% include postJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "about" %}
    {% include aboutJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "lawyer" %}
    {% include lawyerJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "contact" %}
    {% include contactJSONLD.html %}
  {% else %}
    {% include homeJSONLD.html %}
  {% endif %}
```

**This Works!**

```
{% if page.jsontype == "page" %}
    {% include pageJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "post" %}
    {% include postJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "about" %}
    {% include aboutJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "lawyer" %}
    {% include lawyerJSONLD.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "contact" %}
    {% include contactJSONLD.html %}
  {% else %}
    {% include homeJSONLD.html %}
  {% endif %}
```

The error I get with the additional `elsif` is

> Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
>     Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (/home/xxxxx/repositories/legal/_includes/_head.html line 100): 'for' tag was never closed included in /_layouts/default.html
>                Error: Liquid syntax error (/home/xxxx/repositories/legal/_includes/_head.html line 100): 'for' tag was never closed included
>                Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.

Line: 100 is `{% elsif page.jsontype == "lawyer" %}`.

**Edit 1:**

I have got the same error when using case/when

```
{% case page.jsontype %}
  {% when 'page' %}
    {% include pageJSONLD.html %}
  {% when 'collection' %}
    {% include collectionJSONLD.html %}
  {% when 'post' %}
    {% include postJSONLD.html %}
  {% when 'about' %}
    {% include aboutJSONLD.html %}
  {% when 'lawyer' %}
    {% include lawyerJSONLD.html %}
  {% when 'contact' %}
    {% include contactJSONLD.html %}
  {% else %}
    {% include homeJSONLD.html %}
 {% endcase %}
```

It still shows the same error pointing to the end of the head file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `collectionJSONLD.html` was missing `{% endfor %}`

```
{% for member in site.data.members %}
  {
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "name": "{{ member.name }}",
    "url": "{{ member.permalink }}",
    "position": "{{ forloop.index }}"
    {% if forloop.first %}
      },
    {% elsif forloop.last %}
      }
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
     ],
```

Answer (score 1):

In my tests with Jekyll 3.8.5 and Jekyll 4.0.0 both scenarios worked like a charm, no errors, no limitations:

**If/else:**

```
{% if page.jsontype == "page" %}
    {% include 1.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "collection" %}
    {% include 2.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "post" %}
    {% include 3.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "about" %}
    {% include 4.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "lawyer" %}
    {% include 5.html %}
  {% elsif page.jsontype == "contact" %}
    {% include 6.html %}
  {% else %}
    {% include 7.html %}
  {% endif %}
```

**Case/When:**

```
{% case page.jsontype %}
  {% when 'page' %}
    {% include 1.html %}
  {% when 'collection' %}
    {% include 2.html %}
  {% when 'post' %}
    {% include 3.html %}
  {% when 'about' %}
    {% include 4.html %}
  {% when 'lawyer' %}
    {% include 5.html %}
  {% when 'contact' %}
    {% include 6.html %}
  {% else %}
    {% include 7.html %}
 {% endcase %}
```

Any missing `{% endfor %}`, also within the includes files, showed the same error message but the correct line:

> Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (C:/Users/User/Desktop/ruby_projects/jekyll_test/testpage/_includes/3.html line 9): 'for' tag was never closed included in /_layouts/default.html
>   jekyll 3.8.6 | Error:  Liquid syntax error (C:/Users/User/Desktop/ruby_projects/jekyll_test/testpage/_includes/3.html line 9): 'for' tag was never closed included

One of my last thoughts was that you added and removed a specific page, e.g. collectionJSONLD.html every time when testing this (as you confirmed).
There must be a specific thing we can't see as you haven't posted the complete code of the project. Nevertheless, great to read that you solved it! This was a hard one :)